# how to get the gridview cell's value while export gridview to pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datagridview, itext, cells

Currently I try to export an gridview (include an image each row) to PDF file.
I find out that PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(TotalColumns) can help me modify and insert the image to the column. like "table.AddCell(image);"

but how do i insert the gridview (each row)'s each cell's value in to that? (without using findcontrol)

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's asp.net webforms, right? here is the sample about converting a gridview to pdf using iTextSharp: [[^](http://hasheminezhad.com/sites/default/files/hasheminezhad.com/GridToPdf-lib.zip)]

Comment: Thanks VahidN, ya, it is asp.net platform. I still looking at the coding. quite hard to me because i still fresh with this. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, VahidN. it is exportable pdf file. but i got some problems. It is export the html code but not the context like it will export <span id=id >texting</span> but not "texting" in the cells. and the 1s column will go to last and last column will display in the 1st column. do u know how solve it? thanks a lot.

Comment: iTextSharps' html to pdf support is very limited and it has not a sophisticated html parser like browsers. so don't expect that everything should work + you need to change run direction in that file from rtl to ltr. now it should work for you from left to right.

Comment: ok....i already switch the direction back.but it is just a html code. how can i do for display it as a 'real thing'?